# What's the "upgrade path" from Assertion.AssertEquals?

Tags: .net, nunit, assertions

I've inherited some unit test code which is giving me a deprecation warning because it uses "Assertion.AssertEquals":

warning CS0618: 'NUnit.Framework.Assertion' is obsolete: 'Use Assert class instead'

However, I can't see the obvious method in the Assert class that I should be using instead?

AssertEquals takes two objects and a message that can be used to report the error if there's a failure. e.g.

```
        Assertion.AssertEquals(
             "Enqueuing first item should set count to 1",
             1, pq.Count);
```

What's the equivalent method on the Assert class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432776/whats-the-upgrade-path-from-assertion-assertequals/1432806#1432806) presented points to the so called "Classic" model whereas [John Gietzen's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432776/whats-the-upgrade-path-from-assertion-assertequals/1432785#1432785) answer refers to the "Constraint-based" model. Both are right and both do provide the possibility to pass a message for the case of failure.

So let me conclude this:

"Classic" model

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, pq.Count,
    "Enqueuing first item should set count to 1");
```

"Constraint-based" model

```
Assert.That(
    pq.Count,
    Is.EqualTo(1),
    "Enqueuing first item should set count to 1");
```

I prefer the latter one since it reads more like a sentence.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, pq.Count,
                "Enqueuing first item should set count to 1");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Assert.That(a, Is.EqualTo(b),
    "Enqueuing first item should set count to 1");
```

Comment: Yeah but that ignores the message!

Comment: `Assert.That(a, Is.EqualTo(b), "FAILURE")`

Answer (score 0):

Do a full regex replace:

```
Assertion\.AssertEquals(\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\))
```

should be replaced with:

```
Assert.That(\2, \1, \0)
```

And `Assertion.Assert(\(.*\),\(.*\))`

should be replaced with:

```
Assert.That(\2, \1)
```